# Visual Studio 2012 'Publish Profile' to Windows Server 2008 - 'Destination not compatible' error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I am deploying a website form Visual studio 2012 to a Windows Web Server 2008 R2.

I can connect to Web Deploy fine - though I get this error:

```
1>(27/05/2013 21:03:29) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
1>Source (appHostConfig=Default Web Site/myAppMVC4) and destination (appHostConfig=myapp.com) are not compatible for the given operation.
1>Publish failed to deploy.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by right clicking the project (not solution) - clicking Package/Publish Web and *deselecting* 'Include IIS settings as configured in IIS'

Now works fine.

Maybe this is because I'm using IIS 8 on Windows 8 locally - and IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008?

Comment: And also make sure that you are changing the right profile (Release vs. Debug).  Took me a while to figure that out.